# NodeJS: Different session without www

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I have the same problem that these questions but in **[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)**:

- [different session with url's with-www and without-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784654/different-session-with-urls-with-www-and-without-www)
- [Same URL without www different session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667930/same-url-without-www-different-session)

If I write domain.com is a different session that www.domain.com ... **Why?**

It's for some domain rule?

I share here my cookie in express:

```
app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 15778476000,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false 
    },
    key: 'sessionId',
    store: new mongoStore({
        db: db.connection.db,
        collection: config.sessionCollection
    })
}));
```

*Thank you!*

Comment: any solution found? thanks